# retrieve data from movie database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm not a db expert and this is for sure a newbie question.

I've a SQLite db containing data about movies.

The main table (**movies**) contains:

- movie_id (autoincrement, primary);
- title;
- year;
- other fields;

Then I have the **actors** table:

- actor_id (autoincrement);
- name;
- surname;

Then I have the **cast** table:

- movie_id (related to movies table);
- actor_id (related to the actors table, eg. Robin Williams);
- character_name (the name of the character, eg. "Mrs Doubtfire");

In a single query I should retrieve all the characters of a given movie (at the application level I've the id of the current movie to start), name and surname of the actor and a list of the movies (!= this current movie) where the actor had a role:

```
Character_name   |   Actor          |   Other movies where we've seen this actor
Mrs Doubtfire    |   Robin Williams |   Mork & Mindy, Dead Poets Society, ...
Other name       |   Other actor    |   Related movies,...
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
select max(c.character_name) character_name,
       max(a.name) || ' ' || max(a.surname) actor,
       group_concat(distinct m.title) other_movies
from cast c
join actors a on c.actor_id = a.actor_id
left join cast omc on c.actor_id = omc.actor_id and c.movie_id <> omc.movie_id
left join movies m on omc.movie_id = m.movie_id
where c.movie_id = ?
group by a.actor_id
```

Comment: This seems to work but my ignorance has lots of questions   :-)  One of them is: why "max"?

Comment: That's because I'm grouping by actor_id - in most SQLs (MySQL is an exception), a field in a grouped select clause has to be either aggregated or included in the group clause. In this case (because the names are all functionally dependant on the actor_id) I *could* have added the names to the group clause without affecting the rest of the query, but I find it clearer to group only on the required fields - which means that I have to use an aggregate function on the names.

Comment: Mark, I've to study a lot, but your query is a fantastic starting point   ;-)